# Geometric distribution where failure probability is not 1-p

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

The typical geometric distribution is defined from the success probability $p$, i.e., a r.v. G~Geometric($p$), would have PMF...

$$P[G=g]=(1-p)^{g-1}p$$

I have this problem from Bertsekas:
[image]

For part a, the answer is obviously $\Sigma_{k=1}^{10}(0.3)^{k-1}(0.4)\approx0.571$.

But we could also say that r.v. L~CustomGeometric($p=0.4$, $q=0.3$)...

$$P[L=l]=q^{l-1}p=(0.3)^{l-1}(0.4)$$

Where the answer to part a would just come from evaluating the CDF of L, i.e., P[L$\leq$10]. Is there a name for this more generic version of the Geometric distribution?

Comment: The probability that the match ends is $0.4+0.3 = 0.7$. For part (b), it does not matter who wins.

Comment: Not sure I follow your solution to $b$.  This is a standard Geometric Distribution  (with a cut off at $10$.).  The success probability is $,7$ and the fail probability is $1-.7=.3$.

Comment: This question is only about part a. I am just asking if you know of a name for this distribution which I call "CustomGeometric". Is it a special case of another distribution?

Comment: It's not a distribution at all, since the terms do not sum to $1$.  It's just the probability of a particular event.  If you mean the conditional probability that the game takes exactly $k$ moves $\textit {given that $S$ wins}$ then I'd still call it a truncated Geometric (or, at least, a constant times such).

Comment: @lulu Okay, you're right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out, if $L$ is the number of games played until Fischer wins the match, then it is not a well-defined random variable, because Spassky can win with nonzero probability.  In such a case, how is $L$ defined?  For instance, there could be $3$ ties, and the fourth game is won by Spassky.  You can't say $L = 4$, yet the match has stopped:  no more games are played.

A modification to this thinking may be possible.  Suppose we call $G$ the random number of games played until one of the two players wins.  We do not impose a limit to the total number of games played.  Then clearly $$G \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(p = 0.4 + 0.3).$$  Then, given $G$, we know that every game until the final game played was a tie.  The final game, having been won decisively, was won by Fischer with probability $$\frac{0.4}{0.4 + 0.3} = \frac{4}{7}.$$  In fact, this is the unconditional probability of Fischer winning the match, if there is no restriction on how many games are played.  If we do restrict the maximum number of games to $n = 10$, then there is a nonzero probability the match results in a tie, which is $$(0.3)^{10} = 0.0000059049.$$  But if the match is decisive, then Fischer still wins with odds $4:3$, i.e. the probability is $$\frac{4}{4+3} (1 - (0.3)^{10}) = \frac{1428562993}{2500000000}.$$